# Google Cloud data Fusion Checksum file csv

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I just try Google cloud fusion and now I try looking for how to checksum file. in the google fusion plugin there is a MD5/SHA field dataset, but this plugin only hashing each column not file. there is way to hashing file or some suggestion for this issue? I need to do this for check duplicate with previous data on my table.

Comment: Data Fusion does not have any such plugin currently. How big is each file? We have (unmaintained) WholeFileReader batch source plugin - https://github.com/data-integrations/whole-file-reader which you can take a look at. This plugin reads the entire file as a field on which transformations can be applied. However that plugin is discouraged because of performance reasons and potential to run into OOM for large files.

Comment: @SagarKapare thanks for response btw, its solved by hashing the file using sh operator ( vm instance) , but it's quietly not effective. for this case ( csv data from sftp to bq) i deciding to use cloud composer(airflow). Basically the data its not too big because i just processing the delta.